# Getting IllegalArgumentException for null value in using Splitter KeyValueGenerator

Tags: java, split, guava

I am using the guava Splitter as:

```
Splitter.on(",").withKeyValueSeperator(Splitter.on("=").limit(2)).split(<My required String>);
```

My input String is like:

```
A=1,B=2,C=null....
```

If none of value(1,2) for the key(A,B,C) is null then the above Splitter works fine otherwise it fails with `"IllegalArgumentException: Chunk[>null] is not a valid entry"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works OK for input you gave:

```
@Test
public void shouldSplitValues() {
    //given
    Splitter.MapSplitter mapSplitter = Splitter.on(",").withKeyValueSeparator("=");
    String input = "A=1,B=2,C=null";
    //when
    Map<String, String> result = mapSplitter.split(input);
    //then
    assertThat(result)
            .containsExactly(entry("A", "1"),
                             entry("B", "2"),
                             entry("C", "null"));
    // {A=1, B=2, C=null}
}
```

The message suggests it's the error in your input string, i.e. if

```
String input = "A=1,B=2,>null";
```

then I indeed get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Chunk [>null] is not a valid entry` with the code above.

Comment: you are absolutely right, In my case C was itself null